# A blockchain implementation in 207 lines of code

Tags: c++, c++17, blockchain

There is a `blockchain` class with minimal functionality inspired by *naivechain*. It has template *data* and *hash function* parameters:

```
#include "blockchain_block.hpp"

#ifndef BLOCKCHAIN_HPP
#define BLOCKCHAIN_HPP

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <type_traits>

namespace rzd {

template <
  typename T,
  typename Hash = std::hash<std::string>
> class blockchain {

 public:

  struct block;

  using hash_type = std::invoke_result_t<Hash, std::string>;
  using value_type = block;
  using data_type = T;
  using size_type = std::size_t;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using pointer = block*;
  using iterator = typename std::list<block>::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename std::list<block>::const_iterator;

 private:

  std::list<block> chain;

  template <typename It>
  size_type valid_size(It first, It last) {
    if (*first != *begin() || first == last) {
      return {};
    }
    iterator pos{ std::next(begin()) };
    difference_type index{ 1 };
    for (auto it{ std::next(first) }; it != last; ++it) {
      if (it->valid(*std::prev(it))) {
        if (*pos == *it) {
          ++pos;
          ++index;
        }
      } else {
        return {};
      }
    }
    return index;
  }


 public:

  template <typename It>
  iterator replace(It first, It last) {
    if (auto index{ valid_size(first, last) },
        range{ std::distance(first, last) };
        index != 0 && range > size()) {
      chain.resize(range);
      return std::copy(std::next(first, index), last,
                      std::next(begin(), index));
    }
    return begin();
  }

  inline void push(const value_type& node) {
    if (node.valid(*std::prev(end())))
      chain.push_back({ node });
  }

  inline iterator begin() {
    return std::begin(chain);
  }

  inline const_iterator cbegin() const {
    return std::cbegin(chain);
  }

  inline iterator end() {
    return std::end(chain);
  }

  inline const_iterator cend() const {
    return std::cend(chain);
  }

  inline size_type size() const {
    return std::size(chain);
  }

  inline bool operator<(const blockchain& another) {
    return std::size(chain) < std::size(another);
  }

  inline bool operator>(const blockchain& another) {
    return std::size(chain) > std::size(another);
  }

  explicit blockchain(const data_type& data)
      : chain{ { { {}, data, {} } } } {}

};

}

#endif
```

And a `block` actually:

```
#ifndef BLOCKCHAIN_BLOCK_HPP
#define BLOCKCHAIN_BLOCK_HPP

#include "blockchain.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

namespace rzd {

template <
  typename T,
  typename Hash
> struct blockchain<T, Hash>::block {

  using hash_type = typename blockchain::hash_type;
  using data_type = typename blockchain::data_type;
  using index_type = typename blockchain::size_type;
  using hasher = Hash;
  using time_type = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
  using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;

  hasher hash_string;
  index_type index;
  data_type data;
  hash_type previous_hash;
  hash_type hash;
  time_type timestamp;

  hash_type get_hash() const {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << index
      << data
      << previous_hash
      << clock::to_time_t(timestamp);
    return hash_string(ss.str());
  }

  bool valid(const block& previous_block) const {
    if (index != previous_block.index + 1) {
      std::cerr << "Index "
                << index
                << " does not follow by "
                << previous_block.index
                << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
    if (previous_hash != previous_block.hash) {
      std::cerr << "Hash "
                << previous_hash
                << " is not equal to "
                << previous_block.hash
                << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
    if (hash != get_hash()) {
      std::cerr << "Hash "
                << hash
                << " is not equal to "
                << get_hash()
                << std::endl;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  bool operator==(const block& node) {
    return hash == node.hash;
  }

  bool operator!=(const block& node) {
    return hash != node.hash;
  }

  block(const index_type index,
        const data_type& data,
        const hash_type& previous_hash)
      : index{ index }
      , data{ data }
      , previous_hash{ previous_hash } {
    timestamp = clock::now();
    hash = get_hash();
  }

  block(block& previous_block, const data_type& data)
      : block(previous_block.index + 1,
              data,
              previous_block.hash) {}

  block(const block& block) = default;

  block() = default;

};

}

#endif
```

I also wrote some tests for that stuff:

```
#include "blockchain.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
  rzd::blockchain<std::string> chain{ "foo" };
  assert(chain.begin()->data == "foo");
  chain.push({ *std::prev(chain.end()), "bar" });
  assert(std::next(chain.begin())->data  == "bar");
  assert(std::size(chain) == 2);
  assert(std::next(chain.begin())->valid(*chain.begin()));
  assert(std::prev(chain.end())->previous_hash == chain.begin()->hash);
  chain.push({ *chain.begin(), "spam" });
  assert(std::size(chain) == 2);
  std::list<rzd::blockchain<std::string>::block> copy;
  copy.push_back(*chain.begin());
  copy.push_back(*std::next(chain.begin()));
  copy.push_back({ *std::prev(copy.end()), "eggs" });
  copy.push_back({ *std::prev(copy.end()), "sause" });
  assert(std::prev(copy.end())->valid(*std::prev(copy.end(), 2)));
  chain.replace(copy.begin(), copy.end());
  assert(std::size(chain) == 4);
  assert(std::prev(chain.end())->data == "sause");
  rzd::blockchain<std::string> chain2{ "toe" };
  assert(chain > chain2);
}
```

Does it correspond to blockchain principles?

Is there enough methods to call them from Python, for example?

Are there any refactoring possibilities?

Comment: IIRC templates are not binding friendly. Binding might require instantiating it manually.

Comment: Is there a standard block chain API you are implementing? If so can you provide a link.

Comment: @MartinYork I'm implementing something like this https://github.com/lhartikk/naivechain

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of a bunch of Effective C++ warnings by providing initializers for members of `block`:

```
hasher hash_string = {};
index_type index = {};
data_type data = {};
hash_type previous_hash = {};
hash_type hash = {};
time_type timestamp = {};
```

I also eliminated a signed/unsigned comparison by making both `index` and `range` the same type here:

```
    if (size_type index{valid_size(first, last)},
                  range(std::distance(first, last));
            index != 0 && range > size()) {
```

---

It's unconventional to put constructors at the end of a class definition - most of us expect to see constructors, destructors and copy/move assignment at the beginning, right after the data members.  That helps with understanding the basic behaviour and ownership model of the code.

---

This loop looks like it's a `std::adjacent_find()`:

```
for (auto it{ std::next(first) };  it != last;  ++it) {
  if (it->valid(*std::prev(it))) {
```

Could the standard algorithm be used instead, for clearer code?

---

The const overloads of `begin()` and `end()` members are missing from `blockchain`:

```
inline iterator begin() const {
    return cbegin();
}

inline iterator end() const {
    return cend();
}
```

---

In `blockchain`, the comparison operators `<` and `>` ought to be const.  Since C++20, we can implement spaceship operator instead:

```
std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const blockchain& another)
{ return size() <=> another.size(); }
```

And in `block`, `==` and `!=` should be const; `!=` can be defaulted:

```
bool operator==(const block& node) const {
    return hash == node.hash;
}

// bool operator!=(const block& node) const = default;
```

---

Why does `block::valid()` write to the standard output stream?  That looks like leftover debugging, which should probably go to `std::cerr` or perhaps `std::clog`, but preferably neither - provide an interface for code to find more details *if it needs them*, but don't produce output if not requested.

---

> ```
> using time_type = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
> using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
> ```

I would reorder those, to give a automatically consistent pair of definitions:

```
using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using time_type = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;
```

Give consideration to making the clock type a template parameter, with sensible default.  That can help enable high-precision timestamping, for example, or repeatable unit tests using a mock object.

```
template <
  typename T,
  typename Hash,
  typename Clock = std::chrono::system_clock
>
```

---

Similarly, I'd define the container type we use in a single place in `blockchain`:

```
using list_type = std::list<block>;
using iterator = list_type::iterator;
using const_iterator = list_type::const_iterator;
```

Comment: If `operator==()` compares `hash`, then `operator<`/`>`/`<=>()` comparing `size()` seems like a bug.

Comment: Those operators apply to different types.  No comment on whether comparing by size is meaningful, though.  I've just edited to change the return type of `<=>`, since equal size doesn't imply equal chains.